# Trouble when working with Radio button in Angular Dart

Tags: angularjs, dart, angular-dart

I can make radio buttons work and bind to a model. However, when the page loads, no radio button is shown as being selected, even though one is.

Here is the Dart code:

```dart
import 'package:angular/angular.dart';

@NgDirective(
  selector: '[my-controller]',
  publishAs: 'ctrl'
)
class MyController {
  List<String> fruits = ['apple', 'banana', 'kiwi'];
  String favorite;

  MyController() {
    favorite = fruits[1];
  }
}

main() {
  ngBootstrap(module: new Module()..type(MyController));
}
```

And here is the view markup. Once I start selecting radios, the UI updates correctly, and the data binding works. But nothing is selected when the page loads.  Not sure why that is the case.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>
  <body>
    <div my-controller>            
      <div ng-repeat="fruit in ctrl.fruits">
        <input type="radio"
            name="fruits"
            ng-model="ctrl.favorite" 
            value="{{fruit}}">{{fruit}}
      </div>
      <div>{{ctrl.favorite}} is my favorite</div>
    </div>

    <script type="application/dart" src="main.dart"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried your code. After some experimenting I saw that switching the order of the attributes `ng-model` and `value` solves the problem. I would consider this a bug.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>
  <body>
    <div my-controller>
      <div ng-repeat="fruit in ctrl.fruits">
        <input type="radio"
            name="fruits"
            value="{{fruit}}"
            ng-model="ctrl.favorite"
            >{{fruit}}</div>
      <div>{{ctrl.favorite}} is my favorite</div>
    </div>

    <script type="application/dart" src="main.dart"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```